# Confirm that TF2 is using my GPU when training

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am wondering if there is a way to confirm that my TF model is training on my GPU after I stored the training data on it as advised in the TF tutorial. Here is a short code example:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

print('Num GPUs Available:', len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')))

# load data on GPU
with tf.device('/GPU:0'):
    mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
    x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
# define, compile and train the model
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['acc'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, epochs=5)
```

Comment: you can always run nvidia-smi or some similar command line tool to see

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There a couple of ways to check for GPU in Tensorflow 2.x. Essentially, if GPU is available, then the model will be run on it (unless it's busy by e.g. another instance of TF that locked it). The placement will be seen also in the log files and can be confirmed with e.g. `nvidia-smi`.

In the code below, I will assume `tensorflow` is imported as `tf` (per convention and your code).

#### To check what devices are available, run:

```py
tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices()
```

Here's my output:

> [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:CPU:0', device_type='CPU'), 
>   PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_CPU:0',
>   device_type='XLA_CPU'),  PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0',
>   device_type='GPU'),  PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:XLA_GPU:0',
>   device_type='XLA_GPU')]

In order to check if there is any GPU on the system:

```py
is_gpu = len(tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')) > 0
```

From Tensorflow 2.1, this functionality has been migrated from experimental and you can use: `tf.config.list_physical_devices()` in the same manner, i.e.

```py
is_gpu = len(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')) > 0
```

At some point in time the experimental part will be deprecated.

Last but not least, if your tensorflow was built without CUDA (it's a non-GPU version), `list_physical_devices('GPU')` will also return `False`, even if your system physicaly has a GPU.

#### "Is it automatic once the gpu is recognized by TF?"

Yes. To quote after [TF docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu):

> Note: Use tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU') to
>   confirm that TensorFlow is using the GPU.

If it is recognised, it will be used during the training. If you'd like to be dead sure, you can ask for more explicit logging:

```py
tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)
```

Comment: Thanks but how do I make sure that the training is using the gpu? Is it automatic once the gpu is recognized bt TF?

Comment: @Gepeto97 Short answer is "yes". A little bit more elaborate is in the edited text, last section.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way to achieve this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
if tf.test.gpu_device_name():
    print('Default GPU Device: {}'.format(tf.test.gpu_device_name()))
else:
    print(""Please install GPU version of TF"")
```

(or)

```
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

(or)

Few helpful functions appeared in TF:

Tells if the gpu is available

```
tf.test.is_gpu_available()
```

Returns the name of the gpu device"

```
tf.test.gpu_device_name()
```

Comment: From https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/test/is_gpu_available : `tf.test.is_gpu_available` : Warning: THIS FUNCTION IS DEPRECATED. It will be removed in a future version. Instructions for updating: Use tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU') instead. 

Also, tf.Session is only in TF1.

Answer (score 0):

now here in AUG 23 -- use this
`tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`
Source Official TF Install page.
[tensorflow.org/install/pip](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#windows_setup)