# tensorflow 2.0 custom layers on gpu

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Will completely custom-made layers in TensorFlow automatically be run on GPUs? I noticed that in this document (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/rnn#rnn_layers_and_rnn_cells) it seems that the RNN wrappers won't be using CudNN? That means it wouldn't run on the GPU right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your custom layers will still use the GPU and you can confirm that as explained in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60542475/confirm-that-tf2-is-using-my-gpu-when-training/60544417#60544417).

You are right though that the custom layers won't use cuDNN. Why does it matter? To quote after NVidia:

> cuDNN provides highly tuned implementations for standard routines such as forward and backward convolution, pooling, normalization, and activation layers

In other words, using these optimised primitives will enhance performance of the training. Number of examples with detailed explanation is provided in the [cuDNN: Efficient Primitives for Deep Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0759.pdf) paper. Take for instance *spatial convolutions*. Non-optimised implementation would use "naive" approach, while cuDNN uses all sorts of tricks to reduce number of operations and batch them appropriately. GPU is still fast when compared to classical CPU, cuDNN just makes it faster. For more recent, independent benchmarks, check out e.g. [this article](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8721631).

Still, if Tensorflow runs in the GPU mode, complete computational graph will be executed on the GPU (to my knowledge there's even no simple way you could take out portion of the graph, i.e. intermediate layer, and put on CPU).

Comment: What you are saying in your last paragraph is not true, TensorFlow can run ops (parts of the graph) in CPU or GPU, depending on how it is implemented. You can even force this with the statement `with tf.device("cpu"):`

Comment: Sorry if I'm misunderstanding, but I thought the purpose of running on GPU was to use cuDNN? If I don't use cuDNN, doesn't that just make it as slow as running on CPU?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Do you have any examples on how would you run part of a graph (intermediate layer) with `tf.device`? I know you can run separate tasks / jobs, but these AFAIK are independent graphs.

Comment: @cmed123 No. In general, you use the GPU (or other hardware) API to take advantage of its capabilities. For NVidia GPUs, the API is called CUDA. Part of the purpose of the Tensorflow is to provide high-level API for CUDA (which is low-level and tough to program). If you trace execution of your custom Tensorflow code, you will see it eventually calls CUDA and runs on GPU. In situations when you use "standard" elements, cuDNN can kick in and use optimised procedures (see the extra explanation).

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Ah I see thank you, so there's essentially 2 levels of optimization here. Running on GPU CUDA is faster than running on CPU, but then running on GPU CudNN is even faster then pure GPU CUDA. Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @cmed123 Correct. cuDNN is extra layer of optimisation over CUDA.

Comment: @LukaszTracewski Thank you!