# How to run deep sort using multiple GPUS?

Tags: tensorflow, gpu, nvidia, yolov4

I am following [this tutorial](https://github.com/theAIGuysCode/yolov4-deepsort). I have two nvidia 1080 Ti graphic card but I can't the code.

[image]

I have error in line 8 I also have a laptop with one GPU where this code works fine

I changed the code a little bit.

```
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0:1], True)
```

but still same error

Comment: Please don't post pictures of text (code, errors etc).

Comment: "I have error in line 8" => What is the error?

Comment: @User81862311  ValueError: Unrecognized device: [PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

Comment: @JamesZ   Sorry my bad

Comment: Perhaps try the steps recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60544417/7852589) to see if any of them helps

Answer (score 1):

Thanks community I figure out the answer.

Instead of using:

```
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0:1], True)
```

I have to used:

```
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[1], True)
```

and with this modification my code works well on both my GPU without raise any error.